# Error/aborted tests for the test result viewer (Azure DevOps Pipeline)

Tags: testing, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I was wondering what was the ETA for this feature (view Aborted tests in a separate category). Right now, I feel like this is pretty confusing to visualise, since it does not show an aborted test as an error in a clear fashion and that feature is extremely important to differentiate an error from a real fail.

[View aborted tests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kImcn.png)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this issue should not be asked in SO.

Comment: I was told by the support team to bring this issue here. So if that's not valid here, tell the support team that they should study the question...

Comment: This issue is related to the new feature, you can follow the official news recently, and we will notify you here as soon as we have any latest news.